# How to allow nosetests to pass the modified sys.path to the testing scripts in python?

Tags: python

I want to do an automatic unittests for a bunch of files and subdirectories. I built a driver to setup sys.path for module importing followed by invoking nosetests. I need all my testing scripts below it will catch the sys.path for module importing. However, it seems that nosetests will not pass the modified sys.path to the testing scripts. I wonder whether there is a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable? You can certainly modify `sys.path` directly, but `PYTHONPATH` has the advantage of being set at the OS level, and should be passed on to any child processes.

Relevant documentation here: [The Module Search Path](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path)